# How to use Interpolation to fill in missing data

Tags: interpolation

I have a bit of data that looks like this:

```
data = {79., 79.1, 78.3, 78.6, 79., 77.2, 79.3, 79.3, "", "", 79.3, 76.6, \
79.3, 79.8, 78.4, 79., 78.4, 78.4, 79.4, 79.5, 79.4, 79.3, 79.2, \
79.2, 79.3, 79.6, "", 79.2, 79.3, 79., 79.1, 79.2}
```

I'm looking to do Linear Interpolation to fill in the missing data. The `Interpolation` functions with `InterpolationOrder->1` seems to be just what I am looking for. But I can't figure out how to feed the data to the `Interpolation` function in order to get a a sensible result.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to provide the values of independent variable. Assuming that the points correspond to equidistant values of an independent variable, you can do this, for example:

```
int = 
 Interpolation[
   Select[Transpose[{Range[Length[data]], data}], NumericQ[Last[#]] &],
   InterpolationOrder -> 1
 ]
```

Of course, you may wish to scale the independent variable here in some way.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Looking at the solution it bugs me that I was soo close but couldn't quite put two and two together to get it right.

Comment: @MrAlpha Glad I could help! Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

In versions 9+, you can also use the option [`MissingDataMethod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MissingDataMethod.html) after processing your data into a [`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TemporalData.html) object:

```
ClearAll[iF]
iF[d_, o_:1] := TemporalData[Replace[d, Except[_?NumericQ]:>Missing[], 1], Automatic,
   MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> o}]["States"]
```

Examples:

```
data = {79., 79.1, 78.3, 78.6, 79., 77.2, 79.3, 79.3, "", "", 79.3, 76.6, 
79.3, 79.8, 78.4, 79., 78.4, 78.4, 79.4, 79.5, 79.4, 79.3, 79.2, 
79.2, 79.3, 79.6, "", 79.2, 79.3, 79., 79.1, 79.2}

Grid[Prepend[Transpose@{data, iF[data, 0][[1]], iF[data][[1]], iF[data, 2][[1]]},
 {HoldForm[data], HoldForm[intF[data, 0]], HoldForm[iF[data, 1]], HoldForm[iF[data, 2]]}],
 ItemStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, {{{9, 12}, {1, 4}} -> Red, 
  {{27, 29}, {1, 4}} -> Orange}}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
style = {Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, LabelStyle -> {"Panel", 14},
   ImageSize -> 300, PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[.03], Thick}]};

Row[Table[ListLinePlot[MapAt[Style[#, Red, PointSize[Large]] &, dt[[1]], 
    Position[data, ""]], style, PlotLabel -> dt[[2]]], 
   {dt, {{data, "data"}, {iF[data, 0][[1]], "iF[data,0]"},
    {iF[data, 1][[1]], "iF[data,1]"}}}], Spacer[5]]
```

[image]